# C# TimeSpan seconds and milliseconds are out of sync

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I am working on updates to packet simulation software that our team maintains and uses to test other applications we work on. Two of the fields that these simulated packets hold are unix time (seconds) and nanoseconds. This is the time elapsed in seconds and nanoseconds since 1, 1, 1970. We are using c# for this particular app and grab the elapsed time using a TimeSpan object as such.

```
TimeSpan ts = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

packet.SetTimeSeconds(Convert.ToUInt64(ts.Totalseconds));

packet.SetTimeNanoseconds(Convert.ToUInt64(1e6 * ts.Milliseconds));
```

When the packets are captured at its destination and the contents are displayed it appears that the seconds value is lagging behind the nanoseconds value by a considerable amount. The nanoseconds value will tick up to the threshold, roll over, and start ticking up again but the seconds value takes a few packets to roll over. I have checked to see if somehow the seconds value is updated after being set elsewhere in the code but it isn't. The remaining packet values are set after the snippet above and then the packet is sent to the destination using a socket.

I understand that the time for one tick to take place is 16ms and the update could fall between two packets. This could cause them to be out of sync momentarily. In that case I would expect for them to not match for one packet at most due to the tick rate. In my situation this mismatch happens for 3 or 4 packets before the seconds value is updated when producing data every 100 ms.

It is important to note that due to the work environment I legally can not put full source code online so don't ask. Also I have checked all logic after time is set in the packet to make sure nothing is being overwritten. My main question is if this is just an issue with DateTime.UtcNow or potentially getting accurate elapsed time with TimeSpan. This is not a make or break issue as this is just a simulator, but it would be nice to have accurate simulated time in our test packets.

EDIT:

For added information, the issue is experienced even when I do not utilize my packet structure and send the values to a receiver. I have written the following loop to test TimeSpan/DateTime values without the potential for other logic to get in the way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
{

     TimeSpan temp = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

     Console.WriteLine("The seconds elapsed is: " + Convert.ToUInt64(temp.TotalSeconds) + " The nanoseconds portion: " + Convert.ToUInt64(1e6 * temp.Milliseconds);

}
```

Keep in mind that the folowing loop will print out several instances of the same values because the processor can iterate through the loop several times between clock ticks (each tick takes 16ms). If you run the loop you will see that the nanoseconds value ticks up as expected up to 999000000 then rolls over to start over when a new second is reached. When you see that roll over check the seconds value and you will notice that is has not updated. I would post a printout but my machine with internet connectivity has no IDE.

Solution:

As the accepted answer below points out, I was utilizing the convert.ToUInt64 to cast the TotalSeconds value (double) to a Ulong. This was done to meet our in house built library functions. This cast rounds the seconds value which makes the value appear to be inaccurate. I ended up using the Math.Floor(double) function to remove the fractal portion of the seconds before the cast and everything remained in sync. My updated code is listed below.

TimeSpan ts = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

```
packet.SetTimeSeconds(Convert.ToUInt64(Math.Floor(ts.Totalseconds)));

packet.SetTimeNanoseconds(Convert.ToUInt64(1e6 * ts.Milliseconds));
```

Comment: What you saying can't happen.  You are sending TCP data over IP.  Packets can't get out of order because every packet has a sequence number and the Ethernet driver removes duplicate packets and puts the data into correct order.   It sound like there is a bug in the Ethernet Driver for you system.  Check vendor and make sure you have latest version.  The Ethernet driver may be in the mother board of the computer do you may need to update the mother board driver.

Comment: If it is not the driver you may have add locks to sections of the code.  If you are adding item to a list it is possible the an event can occur and data can end up getting out of sequence.  I wrote code a couple of years ago using Asynchronous sockets and had the Asyn method adding to a FIFO and the reading FIFO in main thread and data got out of order.  I had to add locks to make sure the reads and write did not occur at same time.

Comment: jdweng: The packets are in order. That is not the issue. We assign an ID to every packet and time stamp them. The packet IDs are received in order on the destination side as expected, it is the seconds value in the packets that appear to lag behind the value that is displayed for nano seconds.

Comment: How are you determining the time?  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and confirm the receive order and data inside the packets to determine if the issue is on the receive or tranmit end of the link.

Comment: We have wireshark and the values going out through the simulator are the same values coming into the receiver app on the other side.

Comment: Does that mean the TX end is creating the out of order packets?  It is not clear from your description where the issue is located.  If the receiver and simulator are the same then it is not the receiver.  Right now I trying to determine if the issue is after the receiver which would mean a locking issue.  Or if it is before the simulator which would meas the TX end.

Comment: My question is not about message transmission. It is about the validity of the DateTime/TimeSpan tools in C#. We have data transmission under control and know that our packet order and contents match on both ends. The values that are retrieved from the TimeSpan object listed above and placed into the packet has a lagging seconds value. I have done tests where I simply put the above logic in a loop and print out sequential seconds and nanoseconds values and the same issue occurs without sending any data anywhere (so we can rule out data transmission issues).

Comment: MSDN says following : The smallest unit of time is the tick, which is equal to 100 nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.  The following code demonstrates the smallest time period :             int _100nsec = 1;
            int oneSecond = 10000000 * _100nsec;
            DateTime time = DateTime.FromBinary(oneSecond);  I do not know what your code is doing.  One NanoSecond is not 1e6 * ts.Milliseconds.  It is 1e-6  * ts.Milliseconds

Comment: I understand that one nano second is 1e-6 times one millisecond. That means that there are 1e6 (1 million) nano seconds in one millisecond. I am getting nano seconds so for each millisecond I should have one million nano seconds. Hence the 1e6 conversion rate. I am not here to debate basic conversion rates though as my issue is with the seconds value failing to update in a timely fashion.

Comment: You can't use 1nsec because it is smaller that 100nsec.  Net Library uses 1 = 100nsec and won't recognize a smaller number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any inconsistencies. Below is a `TimeSpan` object that I got from your code.

```
TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond    : 10,000
TimeSpan.TicksPerDay            : 864,000,000,000

Ticks               : 15511159080437769         1551115908043.7769  milliseconds

Days                : 17952                     1551052800000       milliseconds
Hours               : 17                             61200000       milliseconds
Minutes             : 31                              1860000       milliseconds
Seconds             : 48                                48000       milliseconds
Milliseconds        : 43                                   43       milliseconds
Sum                 :                           1551115908043       milliseconds (NOTE: we don't have microsecond or nanosecond value bearing properties)

TotalDays           : 17952.730417173341        15511159080437769.0 / TimeSpan.TicksPerDay
TotalHours          : 430865.53001216019        15511159080437769.0 / TimeSpan.TicksPerHour
TotalMinutes        : 25851931.800729614        15511159080437769.0 / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute
TotalSeconds        : 1551115908.0437768        15511159080437769.0 / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond
TotalMilliseconds   : 1551115908043.7769        15511159080437769.0 / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond
```

As you can see, all the values are calculated based on the `TimeSpan.Ticks` level. You can calculate

UPDATE:

Use the below code to get the correct value for just the nano-second portion or total time span in nano seconds

```
public static class TimeSpanExtension {
    const decimal TicksPerNanosecond = TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000000m;
    public static decimal GetTotalNanoSeconds(this TimeSpan ts) => ts.Ticks / TicksPerNanosecond;
    public static decimal GetMicroAndNanoSeconds(this TimeSpan ts) => ts.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / TicksPerNanosecond;
}
```

UPDATE 2:

From your code updates in the question, I notice that you are using `Convert.ToUInt64` to round the number of seconds, causing you to get confused.

```
Console.WriteLine("The seconds elapsed is: " + Convert.ToUInt64(temp.TotalSeconds) +
                    " The nanoseconds portion: " + Convert.ToUInt64(1e6 * temp.Milliseconds));
```

Instead of the above code, you should use the below code to see that there is no inconsistency. You can see the `TotalSeconds` rolling over along with the `Milliseconds`, but `Convert.ToUInt64(temp.TotalSeconds)` will not rollover

```
// C# 6.0 string interpolation syntax
Console.WriteLine($"{temp.TotalSeconds}, {Convert.ToUInt64(temp.TotalSeconds)}, {temp.Milliseconds,000}");

// similar statement without string interpolation
Console.WriteLine(temp.TotalSeconds + ", " + Convert.ToUInt64(temp.TotalSeconds) + ", " + temp.Milliseconds);
```

Comment: Agreed. When making a singular object things look fine. However, if you take the logic I posted, loop it say 150 times, and print the seconds / nanoseconds result values you will see that the nanoseconds value rolls over but the seconds value does not. I would post a printout but my development machine is a standalone without internet connection.

Comment: I posted all of the code. I get total seconds from epoch then convert the milliseconds portion to nano seconds using the conversion rate and set the values into the packet I am sending using a socket. I am working with seconds because it is the native format that I am writing into my packet. Why bother converting ticks to seconds when I have direct access to total seconds elapsed. Lastly, I need just the nano seconds portion of the time stamp.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but my issues are not with nanosecond precision. It is with the lagging seconds value. See my edit to the original post for an example loop that you can run and see the situation I am seeing.

Comment: There we go. Now that makes sense. I dropped the convert.ToUInt64 conversion and things line up. our packet library setter for the seconds value calls for a ulong which is why I am casting it. To avoid the rounding issue I floor the seconds value before the cast and things stay lined up. I am updating my question to include my solution and marking your post as the solution. Thanks again!